# Getting an image of a custom Discord embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to programmatically get an image of a Discord embed. [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/844584075578441761/850531537727389706/unknown.png) is an example of the kind of embed I mean.

I want to get an image like that without having to take a screenshot of the application myself. I'm hoping there's an easy way to get them, otherwise I may have to generate the images myself. I'm using discord.py.

Comment: Why do you need that? I don't think there's any way to do that exactly

Comment: With `discord.py`, no, there is not a way to take a screenshot of the message embed. You probably could do this with some browser automation library, such as `selenium` or `playwright`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Message.embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Message.channel), then get the [embed.image](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.image).url from the returned list.

For example, if you have a message object, my_message, you can do the following:

```
image_url = my_message.embeds[0].image.url
```

(This is assuming you've already got the message object. You can do this a number of ways, e.g. in your on_message event.)

Comment: I need to get an image of the embed itself, not just an image inside it

Comment: @paperman There's no built-in way to get an actual _image_ of an embed - they aren't images, they're embeds. You can use Message.embeds and simply store, mutate, or re-send the embed _objects_, but if you truly need an image, you're probably best off using a webscraping library.